# Windows 7 switches on my mic when a sound plays

Tags: windows-7, microphone

I have a Toshiba Portege laptop with windows 7 installed. Whenever the laptop plays a sound, the microphone is switched on. This is very annoying with headphones. How do I switch off the mic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Control Panel (icon view) and click Sound, go to the Recording tab, right click on the microphone and select disable.

In the same tab, right click in an empty space and tick any selections that are available.